# Stream audio from Raspberry Pi input to Airplay devices

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, broadcast, airplay

Does anyone know if there is a way to stream audio from Raspberry Pi input to an Airplay enabled device such as an Apple TV ?

To sum up I am seeking for an app like http://www.hersson.net/raopx , but that I could run on the Raspberry Pi.

Thanks.